# Display nested json

Tags: javascript, html, json

I want to get the values from this nested JSON, I can in the first level without any issue but when I add a second or third level it displays only the first result and then stops. I´ve tried with a lot of methods and this is the one that gives me the most closer approach to what I want to display.

```
{
"EventInstances":
    [{
    "EventInstanceId":421408,
    "BusinessUnitCode":"65",
    "PublishOnDate":"2021-08-09T00:00:00",
    "PreAppointmentBookingRestrictionMin":null,
    "PreAppointmentBookingRestrictionMax":192,
    "AllowLateRegistration":false,
    "PostApptBookingRestrictionHours":null,
    "PostApptRestrictToSameDay":false,
    "MaxCapacity":2,
    "InstanceType":"Class",
    "RemainingSpots":2,
    "WaitList":false,
    "MaxGroupSize":1,
    "PaymentOption":1,
    "StartDateUtc":"2021-08-24T15:00:00",
    "EndDateUtc":"2021-08-24T16:00:00",
    "StartDate":"2021-08-24T10:00:00-04:00",
    "EndDate":"2021-08-24T11:00:00-04:00",
    "StartTime":"10:00:00",
    "EndTime":"11:00:00",
    "Resources":
        [{
        "ResourceId":119,
        "ResourceName":"Esquivel Govea, Arturo",
        "ResourceType":"Employee",
        "RoleID":"2250",
        "ResourceUnitId":null,
        "ResourceUnitName":null,
        "NumOfAvailable":null,
        "ResourceSubUnits":null
        }],
    "InstanceDates":
        [{
        "StartDate":"2021-08-24T10:00:00-04:00",
        "EndDate":"2021-08-24T11:00:00-04:00",
        "StartTime":"10:00:00",
        "EndTime":"11:00:00",
        "Resources":
            [{
            "EventResourceId":202640,
            "ResourceId":119,
            "EventInstanceId":421408,
            "EventDateId":481803
            }]
        }]
    }],
"EventId":126,
"EventDescription":"BURNING",
"EventCode":"130",
"CategoryName":"JAB",
"CategoryId":16,
"ShowPrice":false,
"RegisterOnline":true,
"ShowOnline":true,
"ShowResources":true,
"ShowNotes":false,
"AutoPublishNextInstance":false,
"LowBookingThreshold":2,
"AllowProration":false,
"AllowProratedCancel":false,
"ShortDescription":"BURNING",
"LongDescription":null,
"TermsAndConditions":null,
"ThumbnailImage":null,
"FullSizeImage":null,
"PricingItems":
    [{
    "ItemId":264,
    "ItemCode":"SER-CG-1STUDIO",
    "ItemName":"1 CLASE STUDIO",
    "Price":258.620,
    "QualifiedMemberPrice":232.760,
    "UsedForPricing":true
    }]
},
{
"EventInstances":
    [{
    "EventInstanceId":421426,
    "BusinessUnitCode":"65",
    "PublishOnDate":"2021-08-09T00:00:00",
    "PreAppointmentBookingRestrictionMin":null,
    "PreAppointmentBookingRestrictionMax":192,
    "AllowLateRegistration":false,
    "PostApptBookingRestrictionHours":null,
    "PostApptRestrictToSameDay":false,
    "MaxCapacity":2,
    "InstanceType":"Class",
    "RemainingSpots":2,
    "WaitList":false,
    "MaxGroupSize":1,
    "PaymentOption":1,
    "StartDateUtc":"2021-08-25T02:00:00",
    "EndDateUtc":"2021-08-25T03:00:00",
    "StartDate":"2021-08-24T21:00:00-04:00",
    "EndDate":"2021-08-24T22:00:00-04:00",
    "StartTime":"21:00:00",
    "EndTime":"22:00:00",
    "Resources":
        [{
        "ResourceId":1308,
        "ResourceName":"CORDERO JUAREZ, SAUL IVAN",
        "ResourceType":"Employee",
        "RoleID":"13660",
        "ResourceUnitId":null,
        "ResourceUnitName":null,
        "NumOfAvailable":null,
        "ResourceSubUnits":null
        }],
    "InstanceDates":
        [{
        "StartDate":"2021-08-24T21:00:00-04:00",
        "EndDate":"2021-08-24T22:00:00-04:00",
        "StartTime":"21:00:00",
        "EndTime":"22:00:00",
        "Resources":
            [{
            "EventResourceId":202658,
            "ResourceId":1308,
            "EventInstanceId":421426,
            "EventDateId":481821
            }]
        }]
    }],
"EventId":127,
"EventDescription":"POWER",
"EventCode":"131",
"CategoryName":"JAB",
"CategoryId":16,
"ShowPrice":false,
"RegisterOnline":true,
"ShowOnline":true,
"ShowResources":true,
"ShowNotes":false,
"AutoPublishNextInstance":false,
"LowBookingThreshold":2,
"AllowProration":false,
"AllowProratedCancel":false,
"ShortDescription":"POWER",
"LongDescription":null,
"TermsAndConditions":null,
"ThumbnailImage":null,
"FullSizeImage":null,
"PricingItems":
    [{
    "ItemId":264,
    "ItemCode":"SER-CG-1STUDIO",
    "ItemName":"1 CLASE STUDIO",
    "Price":258.620,
    "QualifiedMemberPrice":232.760,
    "UsedForPricing":true
    }]
}
```

and my html is this

```
<div id="busunit"></div>
   <script>
        fetch('people2.json')
            .then(function (response) {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(function (data) {
                appendData(data);
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log('error: ' + err);
            });
        function appendData(data) {
            var mainContainer = document.getElementById("busunit");
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var div = document.createElement("div");
                div.innerHTML = 'Descripción:' + data[i].EventDescription+'Categoría: ' + data[i].CategoryName +'<br><br><br> ';
                mainContainer.appendChild(div);
            }
        };
    </script>
```

Example, this works fine:

```
function appendData(data) {
            var mainContainer = document.getElementById("busunit");
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var div = document.createElement("div");
                div.innerHTML = 'Descripción:' + data[i].EventDescription +'<br> ';
                mainContainer.appendChild(div);
            }
        }
```

And this isn´t working

```
function appendData(data) {
            var mainContainer = document.getElementById("busunit");
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var div = document.createElement("div");
                div.innerHTML = 'Descripción:' + data[i].EventInstances[i].Resources[i].ResourceName +'<br> ';
                mainContainer.appendChild(div);
            }
        };
```

Comment: Do you mind illustrating what you mean by 2nd or 3rd level in terms of the expected output you require? It might be good to also provide a smaller example instead of your original json so that it is simpler to explain for both parties.

Comment: Sure, i need to get this ResourceName, StartTime, EndTime, CategoryName and EventDescription, but cant get the values from both i get it for the first one when i try to get ResourceName, StartTime, EndTime, but when i call  CategoryName and EventDescription it displays the values as it should be

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `data.EventInstances[0]` and `data.EventInstances[0].Resources[0]` only have one entry each. You accessed them with i, which is incrementing over data length. Therefore, when you try to access them with i, the first iteration succeeds, but subsequent iterations will give you undefined.

Correct implementation:

```
function appendData(data) {
    var mainContainer = document.getElementById("busunit");
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var div = document.createElement("div");          
        div.innerHTML = 'Descripción:' + 
        data[i].EventInstances[0].Resources[0].ResourceName +'<br> ';
        mainContainer.appendChild(div);
    }
};
```